# Should I use PUT or POST as the HTTP method for sending emails via a RESTful API endpoint?

Tags: rest

I'm leaning toward POST because it's not idempotent, and I want to be able to send more than one email to someone. But I also only want to send one email per trigger, and PUT is idempotent. I think I'm also having trouble understanding idempotency -- I want it so that if a user clicks the same trigger button three times, I only want one email to send. But maybe the next day, if they click on the same trigger button, they receive another email.

The endpoint I'm thinking of using is /email. This is for testing purposes, to test what the email looks like when I trigger a send of a specific template.

Any help with understanding idempotency or whether to use PUT vs POST would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use PUT or POST as the HTTP method for sending emails via a RESTful API endpoint?

Either could be fine.

It may help to review [Webber 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s)

> You have to learn how to use HTTP to trigger business activity as a side effect of moving documents around the network.

The important idea to understand is that your RESTful API is a facade - taking a bunch of useful business activity and hiding it behind the illusion of a boring web server.

So it could be that you POST some form to a resource on your server, with the expectation that your resource will "process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics", and one of the side effects of that processing is the sending of an email.

Which is how we would do it if we were trying to support general purpose HTML web browsers.

But it is precisely as "RESTful" to design a resource model for your server where sending an email is a side effect of providing/modifying the representation of a resource on the server.

---

> I think I'm also having trouble understanding idempotency

Start from the definition in [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-idempotent-methods)

> A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect on the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the same as the effect for a single such request.

Compare

```
x = 7
assert 7 == x
```

with

```
x = 7
x = 7
x = 7
assert 7 == x
```

The point being that if you send an idempotent request, and the response is lost, general purpose components can automatically resend the request, because three copies of the request means the same thing as one copy of the request.

---

When in doubt?  [It is okay to use POST.](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

Comment: In terms of idempotency, if the user clicks the button 3 times I only want the email to send once. But if the next day, they want to click the same button to do the same thing, I want another email to send, basically the same email. In the latter case, I don't want idempotency. But I don't want duplicate responses in the first situation so I do want idempotency -- so, what do I really want, then?